# How to delete previous version jars in a folder using Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

We have a lib folder, where there are many jars of different versions.

like,

ojdbc7.jar

ojdbc6.jar

Now I have to search each jar in the folder and remove if any older version is found. i.e.. I have to remove  ojdbc6.jar in the above case.
Means I have to compare the jars only based on their name, and this check is only for jar files. (As of now, my folder has only jars)

I actually searched a lot to find the solution for this. But couldn't find any.Is there any easy way for this problem using unix/linux?

Comment: Are the all files `.jar`

Comment: yes.. all the files are .jar

Comment: okay based on what do you want to delete the old files? Based on their **name**,  or **date** or ?

Comment: based on their name only..  just compare the name and if old version number is found in the name then delete it..

Comment: Please help me in this..

Comment: You can list them in order and then delete those you do not. Still the question does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Duo to you comment me and wanted a help I provide you this answer. And I am not sure about what you need or want. **Please** check it out and see if it is not an appropriate answer, I will **delete** it.

If I would have these files:

```
├── some_files_00.jar
├── some_files_01.jar
├── some_files_02.jar
├── some_files_03.jar
├── some_files_04.jar
├── some_files_05.jar
├── some_files_06.jar
├── some_files_07.jar
├── some_files_08.jar
└── some_files_09.jar
```

by default the list of the files are in order by their names. So the last one `some_files_09.jar` is the last by its **name**. If I want to delete every `.jar` file except this file, then I can(on command-line):

```
new_file=$(ls | tail -n1)

rm -f !($new_file)
```

And as you can see in the screen-shot:

[image: screen-shot]

### I do not know why the screen-shot cannot be displayed but here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcrfE.png

> **WARNING**: please be careful with `rm -f` and before you do anything you can test what I said with simulated files.

for example, in your **main directory** that you have your files, you can create a **temp directory** with `mkdit t` and then `cd t/` and then `touch $(ls ../)`. Then `touch` command creates a list of simulated file for you in the `t` directory. Then you can test anything you want on these simulated files.

Comment: yes.. but there are many jars like this.. 

I mean

somefile1.2.jar
somefile1.3.jar
somefile1.4.jar


anotherfile1.1.jar
anotherfile1.2.jar

thirdFile2.jar
thirdFile3.jar


like this...

i want to look each and evry jar whether there is any older version available and if so, i need to delete it.

Comment: well you can sort them by their numeric name. **See `sort --help`** Such as `sort -g` or `sort -h`